# Drawing basic shapes with HTML/CSS/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to design a web app that allows visitors to draw and label basic shapes. The visitors will be drawing a basic map of a store. The shapes drawn will need to be stored in a database (their coordinates and sizes) along with their labels and a few options so they can be easily replicated later in a different app.

What's the easiest way to accomplish this on a web page?!

Answer (score 9):

If I was doing this, I'd use [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/).

Check out the demos on the above link, it can do [all sorts of crazy](http://raphaeljs.com/gear.html).

If you're after an actual code sample, I'll have a go using Raphaël if you like.

It works in many browsers:

> Raphaël currently supports Firefox 3.0+, Safari 3.0+, Chrome 5.0+, Opera 9.5+ and Internet Explorer 6.0+.

Comment: What I really need is to allow the visitor to draw boxes and label them in a web app. I won't be drawing with code, but allowing the user to draw and then having to store each drawn element in a database with coordinates for re-creation in a mobile app in the future.

Comment: I know what you meant. Combined with jQuery and some work, you can use Raphaël to allow users to draw "basic shapes" quite easily. As I hinted at in my answer, I could create a small demo for you. For example, allowing the user to draw rectangles? If this sounds too complex, you might want to try a library which already has all this stuff built in. Unfortunately, I don't have experience with this, so I don't know which to recommend. Either wait for another answer, or try Googling "javascript paint canvas" and similar terms.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at http://zwibbler.com

Comment: Zwibbler seems to be exactly what you are looking for. It is a highly configurable graphics editor that you can just drop in to your app.

Answer (score 2):

You can draw some cool shapes using pure CSS.

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/yFn6z/1/

Also more way to draw CSS shapes with borders 
http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/creating-shapes-with-css-borders/
http://www.sendesignz.com/index.php/css/68-how-to-draw-speech-bubble-and-shapes-with-css3
http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/fun-with-css-shapes/

If you want to draw vector shapes of all kinds use [Raphaël javascript library](http://raphaeljs.com/).

Comment: I need the visitor to be able to draw with their mouse, not programatically draw using my own code. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

If its lines and circles, You can use Bresenham's algorithm (Read up more in google, a 1x1px div with the color of your choice represents each point of a line or circle) once the algorithm has been implemented, you can use setAttribute to assign whatever attributes you want to to each line or circle that the user draws and store all the data by separating each shape with some proper delimiters and store it as a text file using FSO. The stored text file can be used as a means to save the users progress.. etc.

Comment: You of course need to have onmousedown and onmouseup events declared as a start and stop for the function implementing the algorithm. Do let me know if it works for you. I have implemented it for some of my works.